# Is my IntelliSense for jquery 1.5.1 working correctly?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2010

Using Visual Studio 2010

I believe it's working correctly, as in after 
any document object focus i.e $(".mycalss").[getting list of all methods and functions]
but I was hoping there would be short explanation of functions etc. kind
of like in c# for types etc. is there no such thing with Intellisense for Jquery?

Also when I click on any opening or closing bracket, be it curly braces } or ) it doesn't
highlight the respective closing\opening bracket like in c# code
so I can't get an immediate overview if I am forgetting to close anything.

Anywhere I am new to programming and manage to literally speed
read through c# code, but this Jquery damn! After 10 minutes my eyes hurt
of seeking the starts and ends of brackets and just following it etc. 
It seems to be a very uncomfortable to  read scripting language, 
too bad for me I can't avoid it on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vsdoc doesn't contain much info on the jQuery methods, but their api documentation is great, so keep http://api.jquery.com/ open for searches for details of jQuery and keep the MDN JavaScript documentation open too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript.

As for bracket outlining, you'll have to use an add-in, I suggest: http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com/ which allows outlining and collapsing for JavaScript and CSS files.